# Finding a string between two strings in a file

Tags: json, string, bash, unix, cygwin

This is a bit of a .json file I need to find information in:

```
"title":
"Spring bank holiday","date":"2012-06-04","notes":"Substitute day","bunting":true},
{"title":"Queen\u2019s Diamond Jubilee","date":"2012-06-05","notes":"Extra bank holiday","bunting":true},
{"title":"Summer bank holiday","date":"2012-08-27","notes":"","bunting":true},
{"title":"Christmas Day","date":"2012-12-25","notes":"","bunting":true},
{"title":"Boxing Day","date":"2012-12-26","notes":"","bunting":true},
{"title":"New Year\u2019s Day","date":"2013-01-01","notes":"","bunting":true},
{"title":"Good Friday","date":"2013-03-29","notes":"","bunting":false},
{"title":"
```

The file is much longer, but it is one long line of text.

I would like to display what bank holiday it is after a certain date, and also if it involves bunting.
I've tried grep and sed but I can't figure it out.
I'd like something like this:

```
[command] between [date] and [}] display [title] and [bunting]/[no bunting]
```

`[title]` should be just "Christmas Day" or something else

Forgot to mention:
I would like to achieve this in bash shell, either from the prompt or from a short bit of code.

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier to map the JSON to an object (OOP Language) and go from there?

Comment: for linux command line tools checkout - jsawk - https://github.com/micha/jsawk and jq - http://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with awk:

```
 awk -F"}," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}' file.json | awk -F"\"[:,]\"?" '$4>"2013-01-01"{printf "%s:%s:%s\n" ,$2,$4,$8}'
```

Seeing that the json file is one long string we first split this line into multiple json records on **},**. Then each individual record is split on a combination of **":,** characters with an optional closing **"**. We then only output the line if its after a certain date.

This will find all records after Jan 1 2013.

**EDIT:**

The 2nd awk splits each individual json record into key-value pairs using a sub-string starting with **"**, followed by either a **:** or **,**, and an optional ending **"**.
So in your example it will split on either **","**, **":"** or **":**.

All odd fields are keys, and all even fields are values (hence $4 being the date in your example). We then check if $4(date) is after 2013-01-01.

I noticed i made a mistake on the optional **"** (should be followed by **?** instead of *) in the split which i have now corrected and i also used printf function to display the values.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well enough for me to get what I needed. Could you explain the second line to me, though...? After |

Answer (score 2):

You should use a proper JSON parser in a decent programming language, then you can do a lot of work in a safe way without too much code.  How about this little Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

with open('my.json') as jsonFile:
  holidays = json.load(jsonFile)
for holiday in holidays:
  if holiday['date'] > '2012-05-06':
    print holiday['date'], ':', holiday['title'], \
          ("bunting" if holiday['bunting'] else "no bunting")
  break  # in case you only want one line of output
```

I could not figure out what exactly the output should be; if you can be more specific, I can adjust my example.

Comment: What do I need to run Python script in cygwin? The output should be: [date]: "[bank-holiday-title], bunting/no bunting. Thx

Comment: Wow, tag `unix` in a cygwin question, that's odd ;-)  But okay.  You'd need Python of course; on Unix systems today this is typically preinstalled.  But in the Windows world there might be better options.  (I added a cygwin tag to your question.)